# How do I centre the text in this custom paper size example?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, margins, geometry, paper-size

I try to use the Swedish G5 paper size (169x239)mm with text width 111mm, text height 165mm, side margins 29mm and top margin 37mm. Why doesn't the text get centred?

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[paperwidth=169mm,paperheight=239mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textwidth}{111mm} \setlength{\textheight}{165mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{29mm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{29mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{37mm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[0-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: Current output.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't mix `geometry` and `LaTeX` syntax, and write simply

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[papersize={169mm,239mm},top=37mm,text={111mm,165mm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[0-5]

\end{document}
```

The behavior you noticed is due to the one-inch driver margins: roughly, the margin is not given by `\oddsidemargin` but rather `\oddsidemargin+1in`. You can change the reference point by using `\hoffset` but that should be done only if you *really* know what you are doing. For all practical purposes let `geometry` do the job for you `:-)`.

Comment: Reading the package documentation for geometry now, thank you.